Single quote command parameter in bash script
I have bash script where I run a docker container with some usb rules like this:
docker run ${USB_BUS_DEV} ${USB_TTY_DEVA} ${USB_TTY_DEVB} ${USB_RAW_RULE}....

USB_RAW_RULE="--device-cgroup-rule='c '$MAJOR_USB_RAW:*' rwm'"

but the quotes get all messed up when I execute the script.
With set -x I can see the command output:
docker run --device=/dev/bus/usb/ --device=/dev/ttyUSB0 --device=/dev/ttyUSB1 '--device-cgroup-rule='\''c' ''\''189:*'\''' 'rwm'\'''

It should look like this instead
docker run --device=/dev/bus/usb/ --device=/dev/ttyUSB0 --device=/dev/ttyUSB1 --device-cgroup-rule='c 189:* rwm'

the echo output from $USB_RAW_RULE is correct: --device-cgroup-rule='c 189:* rwm'
What am I missing?

Read https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050 and run your code through http://shellcheck.net. You need to store your code (list of options) in an array, not a scalar, variable and quote the variable when using it.

Related: When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?

Still no clue on how to fix this. But thanks for the help.
One method that worked was
''
docker run ${USB_BUS_DEV} ${USB_TTY_DEVA} ${USB_TTY_DEVB} "${USB_RAW_RULE}" "${USB_TTX_RULE}"
''
I would like now to use a single var instead of all of them
Like this :
